# Backbone not initializing view. "undefined is not a function"

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm having problem in backbone where it's not finding my view. Here's the code

Here's the views.

```
App.Views.SummaryTableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tbody',

    initialize: function () {
        this.childViews = [];
        this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
        this.collection.on('change reset', this.render, this);
        console.log(this.collection);
    },

    addOne: function (appSummary) {
        console.log('should be receiving model');
        console.log(appSummary);

        var appSumTable = new App.Views.SummaryListView({ model: appSummary });
        console.log(appSummary);        
        this.$el.append(appSumTable.render().el);
        this.childViews.push(appSumTable);
    },
    render: function () {
        console.log('rendiring collection: ' + this.collection);
        this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
        console.log('sending the model');
        return this;
    },
    close: function () {
        this.remove();
        this.unbind();

        this.childViews = [];
    }

});

App.Views.SummaryListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    template: template('app-summary-table-template'),
    initialize: function () {
        console.log(this.model);
        this.model.on('add', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function () {
        console.log('rendering');
        var mod = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(this.template(mod));
        return this;
    },
    close: function () {
        this.remove();
        this.unbind();

    }
});
```

The SummaryTableView has the collection, and the view sends the model to the SummaryListView. The collection is working fine, and the model contains the data. But for some reasons, when I run the code, it keeps saying SummaryListView is undefined. It can't find the view. Am I doing something wrong? I get the error in this line :
`var appSumTable = new App.Views.SummaryListView({ model: appSummary });`

Comment: Facing almost a similar problem , any updates on the issue? !

Answer (score 0):

you are referring SummaryListView before it is declared , hence the error So
you must Declare `SummaryListView` before `SummaryTableView`

the order should be like this

```
App.Views.SummaryListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
      .
      .
});

App.Views.SummaryTableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tbody',
     . 
     .
     addOne: function (appSummary) {
       console.log('should be receiving model');
       console.log(appSummary);
       var appSumTable = new App.Views.SummaryListView({ model: appSummary});
     .
     .
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JQu5Q/23/)

Comment: That's not it. I had tried that earlier, but didn't work. I tried it again after getting your reply - no change. I've created other tables in the same manner as my code shows in the question. After switching the place of the codes like you suggested, now the console shows error that SummaryTableView couldn't be found. Any idea why it's doing this?

Comment: Nevermind!! I don't know what happened. I re-created the view in a separate file, and it's working now. Which was weird because I even verified that the view.js was loaded. I don't really know what happened, I must've done something wrong which somehow was corrected once I recreated the file. It's working now. 
Thanks